# Error no se encontro HttpMessageConverter adecuado

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, http-post

Estoy intentando realizar una llamada a la API de Ogone, todas las credenciales estan correctas, y los parametros que paso en la solicitud son los adecuados. Pero a la hora de mandar la solicitud me devuelve el siguiente error.

> 2023-04-14 09:57:14.949 ERROR 16040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for jdk.internal.net.http.ImmutableHttpRequest] with root cause

A continuacion os dejo mi codigo para que podais echarle un vistazo y me podais decir como solucionar esto.

```
public class CreateHostedTokenizationSession {

//Metodo para contstruir la Url,que despues usaremos
public static String getUrl() {

    return String.format("%s/%s/%s", Base_Url, PspId,HostedTokenizations);

}

//Metodo para rellenar las variables del cuerpo de la solicitud
public static String createRequestBody() {

    try {

        CreateHostedTokenizationPost requestCreatedHostedTokenization = CreateHostedTokenizationPost.builder()
                .locale("en_US")
                .variant("HTPTemplate_Cobadging.html")
                .tokens("")
                .build();
                log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATIONSESSION | BODY  : %s", requestCreatedHostedTokenization));

                return CreateHostedTokenizationPost.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestCreatedHostedTokenization);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

}

public HttpRequest getRequest(){

    log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATIONSESSION | URL  : %s ",getUrl()));
    URI uri = URI.create(getUrl());
    String body = createRequestBody();
    log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATIONSESSION | BODY_GETREQUEST  : %s",body));

    return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .headers(OgoneEsHelper.getHeadersWithSign(HttpMethod.POST, uri).toArray(String[]::new))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(body.getBytes()))
            .uri(uri)
            .build();

}

@PostMapping("/hostedTokenizationSession")
public void hostedTokenizationSession() throws AuthenticationException {

    // Crear un objeto RestTemplate para enviar solicitudes HTTP
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //Crear un objeto de solicitud que incluya los datos de la solicitud
    log.info(String.format(" CREATEHOSTEDTOKENIZATIONSESSION | REQUESTENTITY  : %s",getRequest().toString()));
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(getRequest().uri(),getRequest(),String.class);

    // Enviar la solicitud HTTP al servidor de Ogone para obtener un token de recargo
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    // Verificar la respuesta del servidor y devolver el token si se recibió correctamente
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

        response.getBody();

    } else {

        // Si la respuesta del servidor no es correcta, lanzar una excepsción con un mensaje de error
        throw new AuthenticationException("Error al obtener token de recargo" + response.getStatusCode().value() + " - " + response.getBody());

    }
}
```

}